# Which maven project i choose for creating spring boot web applications in netbeans?

Tags: maven, spring-boot

After a lot of googling i created two sample spring boot projects with maven & netbeans.

First Maven -> web application
[image]

Second Maven -> Java application
[image]

Two projects are working fine.

Which maven project i choose for creating spring boot web applications in netbeans?

Which is best & why?

Comment: You can open the pom file of the project created through Spring Initialzr: https://start.spring.io/  NetBeans opens maven projects natively, Spring will give an up-to-date starter.

Comment: Thank you. They created maven java project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can install the **NB SpringBoot** plugin to create a Spring Boot projects from Netbeans. (http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/67888/nb-springboot)
- Or you can create the project structure from https://start.spring.io/ and import it in Netbeans.
- Also you can choose create a `maven web application` if you want to build a web application, but if you choose `maven Java Application` this will create a console application.

*The choice you choose depends on your need*